# Generate index.html files in different folders to create extensionless urls

Tags: gulp, static-site

I am using gulp to generate static `*.html` files. Currently these are all located in the root folder.

For example:

```
|- about.html
|- contact.html
|- faq.html
```

I would like to host these on a static host, but with extensionless urls. To manage this, I would like my gulp to actually output something like this:

```
|- about
   |- index.html
|- contact
   |- index.html
|- faq
   |- index.html
```

Since `index.html` is the default for my static host, it would result in `about/`, `contact/`, `faq/` extensionless urls.

I am lost on how to accomplish this and would love some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution using `gulp-foreach` and `gulp-rename`:

```
gulp.task('extensionless-create', ['fileinclude'], function () {
    return gulp.src(['./.tmp/*.html', '!./.tmp/index.html'])
        .pipe($.foreach(function (stream, file) {
            return stream
                .pipe($.rename('index.html'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./.tmp/' + file.relative.substring(file.relative.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, file.relative.lastIndexOf('.')) + '/'));
        }));
});
```